# Multi Timeframe Pinescript V5 Input.timeframe Not Working

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am a novice pinescript user and still learning.
I was customizing a script and need to add the option for multiple timeframes. Can't seem to find out how to get it to work.

```
//@version=5
// Copyright (c) 2019-present, Alex Orekhov (everget)
// Parabolic Weighted Moving Average script may be freely distributed under the MIT license.
indicator('Parabolic WMA', shorttitle='PWMA', overlay=true)

length = input(title='Length', defval=14)
power = input.int(title='Power', minval=0, defval=2)
src = input(title='Source', defval=close)
Timeframe = input.timeframe(defval = "60", title = "Timeframe")
highlightMovements = input(title='Highlight Movements ?', defval=true)

sum = 0.0
weightSum = 0.0

for i = 0 to length - 1 by 1
    weight = math.pow(length - i, power)
    sum += nz(src[i]) * weight
    weightSum += weight
    weightSum

pwma = sum / weightSum

pwmaColor = highlightMovements ? pwma > pwma[1] ? color.green : color.red : #6d1e7f
plot(pwma, title='PWMA', linewidth=2, color=pwmaColor, transp=0)
```

As you can see in the script, I have input the line:

```
Timeframe = input.timeframe(defval = "60", title = "Timeframe")
```

doesn't seem to work.

What do I need to change to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Add timeframe as parameter in indicatorline.

```
indicator('Parabolic WMA', shorttitle='PWMA', overlay=true,timeframe="60")
```

Below line is not referred anywhere in script.You can remove the unused code

```
Timeframe = input.timeframe(defval = "60", title = "Timeframe")
```